# PHP: is it possible to return an array with a modified element in one line?

Tags: php, arrays

```
function maybe_one_liner( array $args ) {
    $args["class"] .= " grid";
    return $args;
}
```

Is it possible return with a one-liner?

Comment: Any code that does what you want would be more complicated than what you already have. What you have is as simple as it gets... simple is good.

Comment: There are additional considerations here. In this case, mostly a matter of taste and experimentation, so not really a good subject for in depth discussion.

Comment: Okay. Then I'll just leave you with this: *Everything should be as simple as it can be, but not simpler.*

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit dirty, but it works:

```
function maybe_one_liner( array $args ) {
    return (($args["class"] .= " grid")?$args:$args);
}
```

example input/output:

```
$x = [1,2, "class" => "foo"];
var_dump(maybe_one_liner($x));
```

output:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  int(1)
  [1]=>
  int(2)
  ["class"]=>
  string(8) "foo grid"
              //^^^^^
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Union works, but order is important. [For matching keys, right-hand array's value is simply dropped](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php).

```
function maybe_one_liner( array $args ) {
    return $args + array( "class" => $args["class"] .= " grid" );
}
```

Comment: Err.. and this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/29718804/ looks very similar to this, no?

Comment: Sure. Nothing wrong with having multiple techniques.